# Multiple Select Option in html while getting data from databse

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have to run a mysql query and make Select option to select the given data in my HTML form. 
The issue is No of select option. Because I have to Select option on the basis of item quantity. For example I have one pizza and three drinks. then I need to open 1 select option for pizza and three select option for dirnks.

Here is my CODE:-

```
<select class="form-control" name="dealSizeName[]" id="dealSizeName">
<?php 
 $sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT * From `dealsubcategories` WHERE   `Status` ='Y'"); 
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql3)) { ?>
<option value="<?=$row3['SizeName']." ".$row3['SubCategoryName']?>"> 
              <?=$row3['SubCategoryName']?>
</option>
<?php }  ?>
</select>
```

I have the following Table in my Database:
[image: I have this table in my database]

and I want to make select optoin in my html form like this:
[image]

If in DealA, qty of Pizza is 2 than open two select otion. For burger open 1, for Drink open 3 and for pasta open 1 select option box in my html form.

But I am getting one select option for all every time. How to make it dependable on qty filed of my table.

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want to select multiple options in your dropdown? Or is it something else?

Comment: Yes I want to select multiple option if the qty field is > than one.

Answer (score 0):

There is an attribute `multiple` for the `select` element which helps you choose multiple options.
Since I do not have any knowledge in PHP I will be adding html comments in what you should do in php. This is the basic gist that you should try.

```
<?php 
     $sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT * From `dealsubcategories` WHERE   `Status` ='Y'"); 
     <!-- for index = 0;index < subCategory.quantity; index ++ -->
        <select class="form-control" name="dealSizeName[]" id="dealSizeName" multiple>
        while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql3)) { ?>
            <option value="<?=$row3['SizeName']." ".$row3['SubCategoryName']?>"> <?=$row3['SubCategoryName']?></option>
        </select>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Dear @Sagar, Thanks for your kind response, But I need two seperate select options. but really dont know that how to do?

Comment: @SaleemJafar Ah. So you're saying that depending upon the number of quantities you want to create the number of select options?

Comment: @SaleemJafar maybe this should better help

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Sample data: Item quantities
$itemQuantities = array(
    'Pizza' => 1,
    'Drinks' => 3
);

// Assuming $conn is your MySQL connection
$sql3 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `dealsubcategories` WHERE `Status` ='Y'");
while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql3)) {
    $itemName = $row3['SubCategoryName'];
    $itemSize = $row3['SizeName'];
    
    // Check if this item exists in the $itemQuantities array
    if (array_key_exists($itemName, $itemQuantities)) {
        $quantity = $itemQuantities[$itemName];
        // Generate select options based on item quantity
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $quantity; $i++) {
            echo '<option value="' . $itemSize . ' ' . $itemName . '">' . $itemName . '</option>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).